# Nginx How to configure the Dynamic Proxy for AWS S3 bucket

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3

We have the following nginx configuration, corresponding to each s3 bucket,

```
location /bucketname1/ {
    proxy_pass https://bucketname1.s3.amazonaws.com/;
}

location /bucketname2/ {
    proxy_pass https://bucketname2.s3.amazonaws.com/;
}

location /bucketname3/ {
    proxy_pass https://bucketname3.s3.amazonaws.com/;
}
```

but as you can see, when more and more buckets are created, this location configurations are also increasing.

I plan to make a general location configuration to completely solve this problem.

But for this location:

```
location  ~* ^/([^/]+) {
    proxy_pass https://$1.s3.amazonaws.com/;
}
```

we encountered the error of "no resolver defined to resolve bucketname1",
our nginx is deployed under EC2 Linux machine, does anyone know how I can find my resolver ip or is there a better way to solve this situation without using a resolver?

Thanks

Comment: If you wonder why do you need that `resolver` directive and what does it mean, read [this](https://www.nginx-discovery.com/2011/05/day-51-proxypass-and-resolver.html) post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a complex question. However:

A resolver normally exists for your VPC at IP equal to whatever its base CIDR range is except terminated with a 2.

For example, if your VPC was 10.0.0.0/8, you would find a resolver address at 10.0.0.2. There is also a resolver at 169.254.169.253.

If you ssh into a EC2 in the same VPC and run dig or nslookup commands, you will see it successfully resolving. Try:

`dig @X.X.X.2 <bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com`

OR

`dig @169.254.169.253 <bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com`

Adding this to your nginx.conf should be helpful in resolving those IPs:

```
      resolver X.X.X.2 169.254.169.253;
```

This article explains the two default DNS resolver IP addresses that are created with your VPC:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html

Here is helpful reading from the nginx docs on the server directive:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver

These two stack overflow responses may also be very helpful in resolving your issue:

https://serverfault.com/questions/875150/resolver-directive-for-setting-up-nginx-reverse-proxy

AND

https://serverfault.com/questions/240476/how-to-force-nginx-to-resolve-dns-of-a-dynamic-hostname-everytime-when-doing-p

Comment: Thanks for your help! And one more question~
When I try to add google's dns 8.8.8.8 locally, it will return 403 when I fetch data from s3. Is there a problem with the above regular?

Comment: You are welcome!

Can you provide a little more context please? What is the request that you make which returns a 403? Is it a curl request or is it in the browser?

Are you adding 8.8.8.8 for the resolver directive when you test your NGINX config locally?

Comment: yes, sure, I have add 8.8.8.8 for my local NGINX config, If not, it will return 502 bad gateway rather than 403.
When I want to get the object in S3 bucket, it returns 403
My request is like http://localhost:801/bucket/objectkey
and header is:
X-Amz-Content-SHA256: xxx
content-type: text/plain
Host: xxx
Authorization: (compute signature with AWS access key and secret key)

Comment: Thanks for more context.

 Are you able to make a curl request to it that is successfully fetches the object without proxying through NGINX?

Comment: yes, without the proxy, it returns the true result for the file.

Comment: It is possible that NGINX isn't successfully proxying your authorization headers through to s3. 

Can you look at your NGINX logs to see how it formats the request after you proxy through it?

Comment: yes, but I cannot find any clues in access.log and error.log...

Comment: It returns SignatureDoesNotMatch in the error details